# Automatic scroll to the next cell in a PFQueryTableViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I have a PFTableViewController with PFTableViewCells in Swift.

In each TableViewCell (with a height of 80% the screen size), there is a button. I would like that when a user select the button, there is an automatic scroll to the next TableViewCell.

Any idea how I can make it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just determine the indexPath and scroll to the next indexPath. This example assumes a flat table without sections.

```
func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let point = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView:tableView)
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)!
    // check for last item in table
    if indexPath.row < tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section) {
        let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section)
        tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(
             newIndexPath, atScrollPosition:.Top, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: awsome!         
However how can I call the tableView.indexPath since I am in my TableViewCell and it doesn't know tableView?

Comment: that's because my buttonTapped method is in my TableViewCell class

Comment: It belongs to the *controller*, not the cell. The cell is a *view* and should not manipulate other views (in this case, the table view) managed by the controller.

Comment: Ok thanks. I added : var tableView = self.superview

       let point = sender.convertPoint(CGRectZero, toView:tableView)


Still give me the error: "Cannot Invoke 'convertPoint' with an argument of type "(CGRect, ToView: ?UIView'

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Put the code into the controller (!!). Also, typo: `CGPointZero` is correct.

Comment: Hi! Thank you, it's working, however the code doesn't check for the last item in table -> app crashes at the end... Do you know why?